# If I create a Game Center account, will I lose my village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm worried that my iPhone will break soon and I won't be able to fix it. 
So I want to know if I make a new Game Center account, will I lose the progress in my old village that didn't have a GC account?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have your village backed up on any account, then it is unrecoverable, but if you get a new phone and sign in to Clash with the same account that you backed it up on, you can get it back.